# groupby count in pandas multiple specific condition

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below.

```
Doctor       Appointment           B_ID       No_Show   
  A          2020-01-18 12:00:00     1          0.2
  A          2020-01-18 12:30:00     2          0.3
  A          2020-01-18 13:00:00     3          0.8
  A          2020-01-18 13:00:00     4          0.3
  A          2020-01-18 13:30:00     5          0.6
  A          2020-01-18 14:00:00     6          0.8
  A          2020-01-18 14:00:00     7          0.9
  A          2020-01-18 14:00:00     8          0.4
  A          2020-01-18 14:00:00     9          0.6
  A          2020-01-19 12:00:00     12         0.9
  A          2020-01-19 12:00:00     13         0.5
  A          2020-01-19 13:00:00     14         0.3
  A          2020-01-19 13:00:00     15         0.7
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     16         0.6
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     17         0.8
  A          2020-01-19 14:00:00     19         0.3
```

From the above I would like to prepare below df.

No_Show = Probability of no show.

From the above I would like prepare below data frame

Expected output:

```
Doctor  Appointment        B_ID   No_Show   Session  slot_num   Patient_count
  A    2020-01-18 12:00:00   1     0.2       S1      1          1
  A    2020-01-18 12:30:00   2     0.3       S1      2          1
  A    2020-01-18 13:00:00   3     0.8       S1      3          1
  A    2020-01-18 13:00:00   4     0.3       S1      3          2
  A    2020-01-18 13:30:00   5     0.6       S1      4          1
  A    2020-01-18 14:00:00   6     0.8       S1      5          1
  A    2020-01-18 14:00:00   7     0.9       S1      5          2
  A    2020-01-18 14:00:00   8     0.4       S1      5          3
  A    2020-01-18 14:00:00   9     0.6       S1      5          4
  A    2020-01-19 12:00:00   12    0.9       S2      1          1
  A    2020-01-19 12:00:00   13    0.5       S2      1          2
  A    2020-01-19 12:30:00   14    0.3       S2      2          1
  A    2020-01-19 13:00:00   15    0.7       S2      3          1
  A    2020-01-19 13:30:00   15    0.7       S2      4          1
  A    2020-01-19 14:00:00   16    0.6       S2      5          1
  A    2020-01-19 14:00:00   17    0.8       S2      5          2
  A    2020-01-19 14:00:00   19    0.3       S2      5          3
```

Explanation:

Session = Consider one session a day.

slot_num = slot of that day ( each slot is assumed to be 30 minutes duration).

Patient_count = number patient on the same session and same slot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Series` is used [`Series.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) with prepend `S` and converted to `Series` and strings, similar idea is used in custom function in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and for [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) id added new column `slot_num`:

```
df['Appointment'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Appointment'])
dates = df['Appointment'].dt.date

df['Session'] = 'S' + pd.Series(dates.factorize()[0] + 1, index=df.index).astype(str)
f = lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]
df['slot_num'] = df.groupby(['Doctor', 'Session'])['Appointment'].transform(f) + 1
df['Patient_count'] = df.groupby(['Doctor', 'Session', 'slot_num']).cumcount() + 1
print (df)
   Doctor         Appointment  B_ID  No_Show Session  slot_num  Patient_count
0       A 2020-01-18 12:00:00     1      0.2      S1         1              1
1       A 2020-01-18 12:30:00     2      0.3      S1         2              1
2       A 2020-01-18 13:00:00     3      0.8      S1         3              1
3       A 2020-01-18 13:00:00     4      0.3      S1         3              2
4       A 2020-01-18 13:30:00     5      0.6      S1         4              1
5       A 2020-01-18 14:00:00     6      0.8      S1         5              1
6       A 2020-01-18 14:00:00     7      0.9      S1         5              2
7       A 2020-01-18 14:00:00     8      0.4      S1         5              3
8       A 2020-01-18 14:00:00     9      0.6      S1         5              4
9       A 2020-01-19 12:00:00    12      0.9      S2         1              1
10      A 2020-01-19 12:30:00    13      0.5      S2         2              1
11      A 2020-01-19 13:00:00    14      0.3      S2         3              1
12      A 2020-01-19 13:30:00    15      0.7      S2         4              1
13      A 2020-01-19 14:00:00    16      0.6      S2         5              1
14      A 2020-01-19 14:00:00    17      0.8      S2         5              2
15      A 2020-01-19 14:00:00    19      0.3      S2         5              3
```

Comment: please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61079735/divide-a-column-based-on-groupby-or-looping-conditions-in-pandas 

This is the further calculation on same data set

Comment: Agreed.. only at your level is possible.. Not at all possible for me